# SQL compare values of 2 records in the one table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to look at the current sport that a user takes part in for the latest month (2016-08-01) and count the number who are in a new sport from the previous month.

```
MONTH       |  ID   |  SPORT
_________________________________________
2016-07-01  |  12   |  Football
2016-08-01  |  12   |  Tennis

2016-07-01  |  28   |  Rugby
2016-08-01  |  28   |  Tennis

2016-07-01  |  31   |  Football
2016-08-01  |  31   |  Football
```

So the above example would return a count of 2.

The below code is wrong but I have no idea how to approach this

```
SELECT * FROM SPORTS WHERE currentmonth='2016-08-01' AND ID, SPORT NOT IN
(SELECT * FROM SPORTS WHERE currentmonth='2016-07-01')
```

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: @Xatenev added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each user takes part in only one sport per month you could use this approach:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM(
  SELECT DISTINCT id, count(id) idno 
  FROM `mytbl`
  WHERE `month` BETWEEN '2016-07-01' AND '2016-08-01'
  GROUP BY id, sport) as subq
WHERE subq.idno=1
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bdd23/1).

I have hard-coded the month but you should replace them with variables.

Comment: Worked exactly like i needed it to. Thanks